# Javascript how to append node in its correct index with wrapper

Tags: javascript, indexof, nodelist

I need to get user entered markup (tables) and if the table does not contain a div with a the class="table", I need to add the div & class. I need to ignore any other children, such as p, span, and only target elements with tables.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="table"><table></table></div>
  <div class="table"><table></table></div>
  <table></table>
  <div><table></table></div>
  <div class="table"><table></table></div>
  <p></p>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

You can see in the nodelist above, node index 2,3 both need a wrapper div with the class="table", but ignore the p and span.

```
[].map.call(table, (node) => {
  if (!node.parentNode.classList.contains('table')) {
    const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
    [].map.call(parent, (nodeChild) => {
      const addWrap = document.createElement('div');
      addWrap.classList.add('table');
      addWrap.appendChild(node);
      nodeChild.append(addWrap);
    });
  }
});
```

I have tried this, but it appends the node with a wrapper div at the bottom of the index. How do I get the nodes to append in their correct order with the wrapper div? Thanks.

Comment: So all the direct children of `.parent` that don’t match the selector `div.tabble` should be wrapped with that element?

Comment: Yes, so any time a user enters a table, if they do not add a div class="table" as a direct parent, it should add the div and class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off using a for/loop (using `map` here is an anti-pattern) to iterate over the child nodes of the parent node and replace the current child node with the new created element.

- [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)
- [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)

Inspect the output in dev tools to see the change.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
const { childNodes } = parent;

for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
  const el = childNodes[i];

  // If the node type is an element
  if (el.nodeType === 1) {

    // If element is a div add a class
    // if it's missing
    if (el.tagName === 'DIV' && !el.classList.contains('table')) {
      el.classList.add('table');
    }

    if (el.tagName === 'TABLE') {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add('table');
      div.appendChild(el);

      // Replace the child node with the new div node
      parent.replaceChild(div, childNodes[i]);    
    }

  }
};
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="table"><table></table></div>
  <div class="table"><table></table></div>
  <table></table>
  <div><table></table></div>
  <div class="table"><table></table></div>
  <p></p>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, however it needs to ignore any other elements that do not contain 'table' as children

Comment: That wasn't the original question. It's a bit rubbish to update your question with brand new requirements three hours later.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry about updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood what you're trying to do. This should find child nodes without a "table" class and wrap them in a div with a "table" class. When you run the snippet it won't show any thing as your elements don't have any content but you should be able to inspect them to see the changes.

```js
// get all parent divs
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");

// loop over parent divs
for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {

  // get a single parent div
  var parent = parents[i];

  // loop over child nodes
  for (var j = 0; j < parent.childNodes.length; j++) {

    // get a single child node
    var childNode = parent.childNodes[j];

    // if this child node is type 1 (element node)
    // and does not have a class of table
    if (
      childNode.nodeType === 1 &&
      !childNode.classList.contains("table")
    ) {
      // create a new div element
      var wrap = document.createElement('div');
      // give it a class of table
      wrap.classList.add("table");
      // append a clone of the child node
      wrap.appendChild(childNode.cloneNode());
      // replace the old child node with the wrapped child node
      parent.replaceChild(wrap, childNode);
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="table"></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
  <table></table>
  <div></div>
  <div class="table"></div>
</div>
```